# Sort / positioning pictureboxes like a grid in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net

I have **1 textbox** with *dynamic* integer number as text (can be 1 to 35) (number of products) also **35** hidden pre-created **pictureboxes** (picturebox1,picturebox2,etc) ('cause i dont know how to create at runtime and reference (handle) later propperly without errors) then, with a loop **i set to visible** **just the** *dynamic* number of **pictureboxes i need** (depending number of products)

```
For i As Integer = 1 To NumberOfProducts.Text
        If Me.Controls.ContainsKey("PictureBox" & i) Then
            Me.Controls("PictureBox" & i).Visible = True
        End if
next
```

then, i create a system to determine best (table) picture width/hieght dimentions depending the number of products available... to display *like a grid* with the best screen-fill (into a vertical display).... for 31-35 products the grid must be 5columns*7rows, for 21-24 products must be 4x6, 3prod. must be 2x2, etc...

```
If Val(NumberOfProducts.Text) > 30 Then
        grosso = Me.Width / 5
        lungo = Me.Height / 7
        Horix.Text = "5"
        Vertix.Text = "7"
    ElseIf Val(NumberOfProducts.Text) > 20 Then
        grosso  = Me.Width / 4 
        lungo = Me.Height / 6
        Horix.Text = "4"
        Vertix.Text = "6"
    ElseIf Val(NumberOfProducts.Text) > 2 Then
        grosso  = Me.Width / 2 
        lungo = Me.Height / 2
        Horix.Text = "2"
        Vertix.Text = "2"
    ElseIf Val(NumberOfProducts.Text) > 1 Then
        grosso = Me.Width / 1 
        lungo = Me.Height / 2
        Horix.Text = "1"
        Vertix.Text = "2"
    ElseIf Val(NumberOfProducts.Text) = 1 Then
        grosso = Me.Width / 1 
        lungo = Me.Height / 1
        Horix.Text = "1"
        Vertix.Text = "1"
    End If
```

Then a list of the textboxes getting "grosso" value as ".width" and "lungo" as ".height".... *'cause i think its the most semi-automated way to assign the same setting to all pictureboxes at my form..*

i create the Horix.text and vertix.text values just if it could be used as reference later... I suppose i must to locate the first picturebox (the same position for all grid possibilities as reference to the other pictureboxes position)

```
 PictureBox1.Location = New Point(0, 0)
```

At this point **i dont know what to do!!, to set the pictureboxes positions simulting a grid!!**  i belive i must use a loop  **after positioning the first picturebox, loop from box#2 to numberofproducts available**... subtracting 1 to horix.text (maximum items at each row) and check on each loop if its ">" than horix... then a jump referencing the last picturebox (.top + picturebox.height...  and also substract 1 to vertix.text value too... until 0 but:

**i dont know how to set the new position referencing the last picturebox on the same row!!  i've tried:**

```
for i as integer = 2 to numberofproducts.text
If Me.Controls.ContainsKey("PictureBox" & i) Then
            Me.Controls("PictureBox" & i).left = "PictureBox" & i -1).left
        End if
next
```

but it dont works, i get ".left is not controls property" or some like that  then **i also dont know how to add and determine when to jump to the next row or column**... any suggestion?? (code sample)

Comment: You must convert the control to the corresponding type, like `Dim p1 As PictureBox= CType(Me.Controls("PictureBox" & i"), PictureBox)` and then `p1.Left=...`

Comment: Have you considered using a flowLayoutPanel?

Comment: @Pikoh @user6144226 Many thanks, now it works!!  i mix both both answers adding flowlayoutpanel and adding the line under this previous line:
               Me.Controls("PictureBox" & i).Visible = True

 `               Me.Controls("PictureBox" & i).Margin = New Padding(0)
                Dim p1 As PictureBox = CType(Me.Controls("PictureBox" & i), PictureBox)
                FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(p1)
            End If
        Next `